# How to display a prompt for entering password in power shell while using param()

Tags: windows, powershell

How do i make the password field appear as a prompt for the user in the Parameter context of a function?

This is the code I have already:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Enter Appliance Host Name")][string]$hostname,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage='Enter Appliance Username')][string]$username,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage='Enter Appliance Password')][string]$password,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,HelpMessage='Enter Appliance Proxy if required')][string]$proxy=""
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a method in the parameter part of a function.

Try running it like this:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Enter Appliance Host Name")][string]$hostname,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,HelpMessage="Enter Credentials here")][System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential = (Get-Credential)
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,HelpMessage='Enter Appliance Proxy if required')][string]$proxy=""
)
```

You can also parse the username and password directly to the function and create the Credential Object in the function:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Enter Appliance Host Name")][string]$hostname,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage='Enter Appliance Username')][string]$username,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage='Enter Appliance Password')][string]$password,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,HelpMessage='Enter Appliance Proxy if required')][string]$proxy=""
)
$password = ConvertTo-Securestring -string $password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$username", $password)
```

Comment: is it possible to enter username and password in command line using this. Like,  ./example.ps1 -hostname <somename> -Credentials.username  - Credentials.password.  Like Can I have that option of not being prompted for password when I enter -Credentials <username>. I want to have both functionalities.

Comment: @SushruthN yes. I updated the answer with an explanation of how to do so.
With the secon way you can do `-username "user" -password "passwd"` and the function creates the credential object.

Comment: I got this error with the updated code.New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".

Comment: It works perfectly when I try it.
What is your input?
The error appears mostly when you dont format the password to a secure-string.

Comment: Can u send me the command line which I have to execute. Can you send an example?

Comment: @SushruthN If you want to test if the creation of the credential works just use the last two lines of my answer (`$password` and `$username` are strings you should  allready have defined)